# Delete certain numbers among other numbers in a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to delete special numbers from a list that contains also other numbers which should not be affected.

The list looks like this:

```
[1, 
, 00:00:03,950, 00:00:06,840, 
, effective, argumentation, central, 

, 2, 
, 00:00:06,840, 00:00:09,180, 
, term, thinking, topic, 

, 3, 
, 00:00:09,180, 00:00:10,830, 
, previously, section, course, 

... and so on]
```

Now, I want to delete only the single numbers plus the comma afterwards (here: 1, 2, 3) but not the timestamps (or any part of the timestamps).

What should be considered, is that these numbers could theoretically increase to 10 or even more digits, there is no constraint.

For this task, I have tried the following regular expressions (among others):

`result = re.sub(r"^\d{1,},$", "", data)`

`result = re.sub(r"^\d{1,},\n", "", data)`

But nothing I can think of works for my task. Either a part of the timestamps is also deleted or the numbers in question are not deleted at all.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you @anubhava! Unfortunately, it works for all numbers except for the very first number (1,). Is there a way to delete this one as well?

Comment: @anubhava: I don't know why but the first number still resists to be deleted. :-(

Comment: may be try: `re.sub(r"(^|\W+)\d+,\s*", r'\1', data)`

Comment: Can you just add a example input and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

As you are dealing with multiline test, you can use anchors `^` and `$` without using `MULTILINE` mode. However for your case you can use a simple regex to remove all numbers followed by comma:

```
re.sub(r"(^\W*|\s)\d+,\s*", r'\1', data)
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(^\W*|\s)`: Matches start position followed by 0+ non-word characters and OR else a whitespace and capture in group #1
- `\d+,\s*`: Match 1+ digits followed by a comma and 0 or more whitespaces
- `\1`: Is replacement that puts back text captured in group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjC7Ne/1https://regex101.com/r/fjC7Ne/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This regex deletes indeed all target numbers, even the "1" at the beginning. But for some reason, the regex affects the timestamps as well so that the two numbers after the first colon all change to "00". I am still working on that.